# ERR_TARGET_NOT_FOUND: Target not found

Tags: android, sdk, ionic3, android-emulator, command-line-interface

i am trying emulate the android with this command:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --target=android-26
```

And return this error:

```
[native-run] ERR_TARGET_NOT_FOUND: Target not found: android-26
```

So i run this command to see the avaliable android targets and return this:

```
id: 1 or "android-23"
 Name: Android API 23
 Type: Platform
 API level: 23
 Revision: 3

id: 2 or "android-26"
 Name: Android API 26
 Type: Platform
 API level: 26
 Revision: 2
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks!